# Mod-$R$, Mod-$S$ and Mod-$R \otimes S$

Tags: commutative-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $R,S,T$ be commutative rings and assume that $R,S$ are $T$-algebras.

In an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104222/modules-over-a-tensor-product) question, Pierre-Yves Gaillard gives an example of an $R \otimes_T S$-module that cannot be written as the tensor product of an $R$-module and an $S$-module (there, $T=k$, $R=S=k^2$ where $k$ is a field).

I'm interested in the relation between the module categories Mod-$R$, Mod-$S$ and Mod-$R \otimes_T S$. Is there some kind of general operation (a "tensor product") on abelian categories that takes Mod-$R$, Mod-$S$ and  Mod-$T$ (or $T$ itself) and produces Mod-$R \otimes_T S$?

Comment: Dear Sebastian: If $M$ is an $R$-module and $N$ is an $T$-module, then there is a unique structure of $R\otimes_TS$-module on $M\otimes_T N$ satisfying $$(r\otimes s)(x\otimes y)=rx\otimes sy$$ for all $r\in R,s\in S,x\in M,y\in N$.

Comment: @Sebastian: Well, by the general theory of Morita equivalence, $\textrm{Mod-}R$ is equivalent to $\textrm{Mod-}S$ if and only if $R \cong S$ as rings, so in theory, yes, it should be possible if you are willing to restrict your attention to commutative rings. But the general case looks more doubtful, as the passage from $R$ to $\textrm{Mod-}R$ loses information.

Comment: How does the counter example of Pierre and the result on the Deligne Tensor Product not clash? I have been trying to learn these things lately and am stuck on this thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [Deligne's tensor product](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Deligne+tensor+product+of+abelian+categories), [Kelly's tensor product](http://www.mat.uc.pt/~workct/slides/Ignacio.pdf), as all as the coproduct of cocomplete $\otimes$-tensor categories. They all have the property $\mathsf{Mod}(R) \otimes_k \mathsf{Mod}(S) \simeq \mathsf{Mod}(R \otimes_k S)$. See [Schäppi's work](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6358) for generalizations to schemes and quasi-coherent sheaves.

Comment: Thank you for digging up the old question! I had come across the Deligne tensor product in the meantime, but the other two references are new to me.

Comment: How to prove that deligne's tensor of Mod-R and Mod-S is Mod-$R\otimes S$？In Eitingof's book, he said it is 'easy'.